# speed up the iteration over 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I need to fill up the array cells with data from text files where each row represent an item that its columns need to be filled up with data from text file different than other rows.
I used numpy to iterate over 2D array but it's extremely slow how can I improve the performance?

```
items_list=(save_file+'list_items.txt')
item_ids=np.loadtxt(items_list,dtype='str')
num=len(item_ds)
print(num)

try:
   X=np.zeros(shape=(90532,9216))
   for i in range(0,num):
      #load the item features rom txt file to fill the matrix
      item_fea=head+'......%s.txt'%(item_ids[i])
      fea=np.loadtxt(item_fea,dtype='str')
      for j in range(0,9216):
          print(i,item_ids[i])
          X[i,j]=fea[j]
  print(X.shape)
  output=save_file+'......npy'
  np.save(output,X)
except:
print('error')
e=sys.exc_info()
print(e)
pass
```

Comment: Have you tried `X[i,:]=fea`? instead of the inner loop?

Comment: A try-except that just prints `'error'` and `sys.exc_info()` isn't actually any better than just letting the exception propagate. It's substantially worse, actually.

Comment: I did not try x[i:], I'll modify the code and see. Thank you

Comment: Thank you, your feedback enhanced the performance significantly. I never thought of these modifications.